# Validación de dos campos CURRENCY

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

tengo dos campos: `ValorFacturado y CargoFIjoMensual`
la idea es que el cargo fijo no sea mayor al valor facturado, como puedo hacer esa validación, tengo entendido que por medio de javascript, pero comos sería la estructura lógica? 
muchas gracias

Comment: Necesito entender el contexto, porque puedes hacer esa validación desde el front-end o desde el back-end, aunque la lógica es la misma y la sintaxis muy probablemente también, cambiaría el método para obtener los valores de ValorFacturado y CargoFijoMensual.

Comment: Hola amigo, gracias por la disposición, el origen de los datos, vienen desde un modelo, aclarando que uso MVC, las data annotations las validé en tipo currency, donde: ValorFacturado pertenece a la tabla FACTURACIÓN y CargoFijoMensual a la tabla Servicio, no se que datos puntuales necesites para entender el contexto. gracias de antemano.

Comment: Si tu restricción está en que no debes guardar o editar un registro en la base de datos.

Answer (score 0):

Todo dependerá del origen de los campos `ValorFacturado` y `CargoFijoMensual` estos deben ser valores numéricos.

```js
var ValorFacturado = 100.25;
var CargoFIjoMensual = 100.30;

if(CargoFIjoMensual > ValorFacturado){
  document.write('CargoFIjoMensual es mayor');
}else{
  document.write('CargoFIjoMensual es menor');
}
```

En caso que los campos vengan con algún formato, este formato deberá ser removido, para poder hacer el tratamiento y aplicar los [operadores de comparación](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp).

Answer (score 0):

Si utilizas jQuery, puedes obtener esos valores desde un archivo JavaScript así:

```
var valorFacturado = $("#txtValorFacturado").val();
var cargoFijoMensual= $("#txtcargoFijoMensual").val();
```

donde `txtValorFacturado` es el id de tu campo de texto.

Para obtener el id exacto, puedes utilizar las herramientas de desarrollo de tu navegador e inspeccionar el DOM, y así obtener el id, te dejo un enlace para saber un poco de esto: [Herramientas para desarrolladores de Chrome Developer Tools](https://support.google.com/dfp_premium/answer/4497389?hl=es).

Ahora, puedes utilizar una función en JavaScript que te regrese una variable tipo bool, en la cual vas a comparar si una variable es mayor que otra. Así sería el código:

```
function validarCantidades(){
    var valorFacturado = $("#txtValorFacturado").val();
    var cargoFijoMensual= $("#txtcargoFijoMensual").val();

    return cargoFijoMensual > valorFacturado;
}
```